# Disable "feature" that leaves attribute values on space keypress

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2013, there's a new (or newly enabled by default) *feature* that moves the cursor out of the quotes surrounding the `class` attribute value (and possibly others) on <kbd>space</kbd> keypress.  That's a super swell feature except for that the `class` attribute values are space delimited.

For example:

```
                // v when I press space here it moves the cursor
<div class="example unicorns" 
                           // ^ here
```

So, in the previous example, after I <kbd>space</kbd> I have to:

1. Redirect the cursor back inside the `class` value
2. <kbd>space</kbd>
3. Continue on with typing `unicorn`.

So my question: **What is this called and how can I disable it?!**

Comment: I'm not going to delete it in the hopes the wording will help others find the solution